# jest giving SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on type ErrorHandler

Tags: jestjs

Getting this error in my jest call:

```
    /xx/mobile/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

- react: 16.13.1
- react-native: 0.64.4
- jest: ^27

Have tried most ideas by now including all variations of `transformIgnorePatterns`

Please suggest.

Comment: I have same problem. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `jest.config.js` file:

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)'
  ]
```

This is from https://docs.expo.dev/guides/testing-with-jest/#configuration

I've been battling with various issues like this. Also try installing the `jest-expo` preset (`npm i --save-dev jest-expo`). Here is my working `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  resetMocks: true,
  setupFiles: ['./core-js.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)'
  ]
};
```

Comment: this worked for some time till I realised I would have to add pretty much entire node_modules folder in the ignore patterns. I think there is a flaw in my babel, jest config which is causing this. not found the solution yet.

Comment: I've edited my answer - I've been battling with all this myself and now have things working nicely. Let me know if it works for you. You can probably ignore the `setupFiles` part

Comment: In my case If you're using pnpm, you can add the following to your jest.config to ignore pnpm files.
`transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/.pnpm/(?!@react-native|react-native)']`

Source: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/20073#issuecomment-1795307968